# Laravel 5.5 Middlewares

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Espero que puedan ayudarme, Necesito hacer un control (middleware) un filtro digamos, que sólo puedan editar un registro la persona que lo creo. Parece fácil pero soy novato en el tema. Estube leyendo mucho, pero todos hablan del usuario logueado en el sistema, eso sí logre hacerlo, lo que no puedo es decirle al middleware que mire un campo de la tabla que contiene el id del usuario para verificar si es el mismo que el usuario logueado.

Intenté  con lo siguiente

```
if ($request->user_id != auth()->user()->id) {
```

pero el request me da vacío al mostrarlo

```
if ($request->user_id != auth()->user()->id) {
        echo "Request:" . $request->user_id;
        echo "<br />";
        echo "AUT: " . auth()->user()->id;
        \Session::flash('message-danger', 'No está habilitado para realizar esta acción.');
       // return redirect()->route('ocprotesis.index');
    }
```

por ejemplo en ese código AUT me devuelve 1, lo cual esta bien, pero Request me devuelve NADA

Entiendo que el middleware se ejecuta antes de llegar al controlador en la ruta. En la ruta agregue el middleware y pasa por ese IF pero no puedo determinar que si el usuario logueado NO es quién creo este registro no pueda editarlo. Eso es lo que necesito, gracias !!!!

Comment: ¿Donde hace dicho `if` ?¿De donde sale la variable `$request`? , el $request lo controlas tú desde la vista .¿tienes algún campo `user_id` ?

Comment: Te sugiero que utilices [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#creating-policies) en lugar del middleware.